# Transferring Data from old to new PS3

Tags: ps3

So I needed a bigger PS3 and didn't transfer my data over right when I got my new one. I have some single player games that I got really far in saved on my old one but don't want to restart them on my new one. I plan on selling my old one soon so I want to transfer all my saved data over without deleting anything on my new PS3. Any way I can do that?

Comment: To make it more clear: So you want to put your savegames from an older ps3 to a new one and just want to know how it works?

Answer (score 2):

The PS3 system software has a built-in function that makes migration to another system easy and safe (no loss of save data or user data) 
It can be done using one of the following 2 ways available:

- the backup and restore utility uses an external USB drive that is formatted to FAT32 and creating backup data that is restored on the new system.  Official documentation for this process is available at this [link](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/798/~/ps3-backup-utility)
- the data transfer utility uses an Ethernet cord to directly connect the two systems together and transferring/moving most of the system data over to the new console directly. Official documentation for this process is available at this [link](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1935/kw/Transfer%20)

Both of these processes are started from the system settings in the settings section of the XMB ( system menu)

Keep in mind that both processes completely wipe the system the data is being transferred to before the data is transferred.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to summarize the information at links, when they're critical to answering the question.  That way, if the site ever goes down, your answer is still good.